# With Ripple, how can I move my wallet to/from Payward?

Tags: ripple, ripple-client

When I created my ripple wallet, I selected local computer.  Now I want to be able to access my wallet from any computer.  How can I move my ripple wallet to the server?

Or suppose I want to remove my wallet from the Ripple server (why would I want to do this?), what is the correct approach?

Comment: @Downvoter / Closer: [According to meta Ripple questions are on topic](http://meta.bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/335/1878) .  Please provide constructive feedback for the down vote.

Answer (score 2):

I'm seeking for an authoritative answer for myself, but it seems the answer to the first question is:

> On account creation (*and whenever you login*) you can set the "Fetch
>   wallet from" option to one of "Payward", "Payward and Local Browser"
>   or "Local Browser".

[source](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/9003/5363)